# Mod rewrite with certain page

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Hey my modrewrite works just fine

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?cCategory=$1 [L]
```

so www.studybuddy.at/impressum will be www.studybuddy.at/index.php?cCategory=impressum

but how can i prevent this url from being rewritten:

> `http://www.studybuddy.at/?`
>   `state=a8089ccb4ba0631bc8f3fc2a6ac42a7a&code=AQDnf9prmi9nn0q5uisgOeey-`
>   `7LJOKDe0DNqCLpi9qevTJIT6eD1PB__rizVpP-`
>   `39TH2hhLAoah18pXIcLLZy76Vs8LOQp_2ElS1m5O2daJ6FdO2M5rkteqx5ckbFsezBWuQk7hNL2B-`
>   `PpkW2Pqgnu4Rc1umZrBrvr8rTeoWigwHk0Gtq8ToZ1inAxrlKEK652s#_=_`

this ends in an endless loop...

please help...i'm just new to this rewrite thing

thx

Answer (score 0):

You can add a rule of exclusion of character "?" ?

I think it's something like : ^[^?]